# Buttons in ViewPage

Tags: android, android-studio

Does anyone know if I can put some buttons on a ViewPage in Android Studio?

I'm trying to make my first app and it needed that they can move between screens with their fingers, but these screens have buttons. Someone knows how to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its easy !

1. Layout ViewPager

   ```
   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
       android:id="@+id/vpPager"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
   ```
2. Define Fragments

   public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
       // Store instance variables
       private String title;
       private int page;

   ```
   // newInstance constructor for creating fragment with arguments
   public static FirstFragment newInstance(int page, String title) {
       FirstFragment fragmentFirst = new FirstFragment();
       Bundle args = new Bundle();
       args.putInt("someInt", page);
       args.putString("someTitle", title);
       fragmentFirst.setArguments(args);
       return fragmentFirst;
   }

   // Store instance variables based on arguments passed
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       page = getArguments().getInt("someInt", 0);
       title = getArguments().getString("someTitle");
   }

   // Inflate the view for the fragment based on layout XML
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
       TextView tvLabel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvLabel);
       tvLabel.setText(page + " -- " + title);
       return view;
   }
   ```

   }
3. Setup FragmentPagerAdapter

   public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
       // ...

   ```
   public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
   private static int NUM_ITEMS = 3;

       public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
           super(fragmentManager);
       }

       // Returns total number of pages
       @Override
       public int getCount() {
           return NUM_ITEMS;
       }

       // Returns the fragment to display for that page
       @Override
       public Fragment getItem(int position) {
           switch (position) {
           case 0: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment
               return FirstFragment.newInstance(0, "Page # 1");
           case 1: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment different title
               return FirstFragment.newInstance(1, "Page # 2");
           case 2: // Fragment # 1 - This will show SecondFragment
               return SecondFragment.newInstance(2, "Page # 3");
           default:
               return null;
           }
       }

       // Returns the page title for the top indicator
       @Override
       public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
           return "Page " + position;
       }

   }
   ```

   }
4. Apply the Adapter

   public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
       FragmentPagerAdapter adapterViewPager;

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
       ViewPager vpPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vpPager);
       adapterViewPager = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
       vpPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);
   }

   // ...
   ```

   }
5. Setup OnPageChangeListener

   // Attach the page change listener inside the activity
   vpPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

   ```
   // This method will be invoked when a new page becomes selected.
   @Override
   public void onPageSelected(int position) {
       Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, 
                   "Selected page position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

   // This method will be invoked when the current page is scrolled
   @Override
   public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
       // Code goes here
   }

   // Called when the scroll state changes: 
   // SCROLL_STATE_IDLE, SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING, SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING
   @Override
   public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
       // Code goes here
   }
   ```

   });

if you need more info see this link (it also explain how to use tabs) :

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter